# Wild Card Searches in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, search, indexing, wildcard, azure-cognitive-search

I'm exploring ACS to see whether it fits into our requirement. I took the Hotels index and trying to perform wild card queries but it doesnt work as expected.

For Eg. for the document below -

```
        "HotelId": "24",
        "HotelName": "Gacc Capital",
        "Description": "Chic hotel near the city.  High-rise hotel in downtown, walking distance to theaters, restaurants and shops, complete with wellness programs.",
        "Description_fr": "Hôtel chic près de la ville.  Hôtel de grande hauteur dans le centre-ville, à distance de marche des théâtres, des restaurants et des magasins, avec des programmes de bien-être.",
        "Category": "Budget",
        "Tags": [
            "laundry service",
            "pool",
            "bar"
        ],
        "ParkingIncluded": false
```

search request on HotelName with "Cap" as starting word doesnt return above the document.

```
$filter=search.ismatch('/.Cap.*/', 'HotelName')
```

Where as the search request on Capital returns it.

Same is the case with infix search.

```
$filter=search.ismatch('/.*Cap.*/', 'HotelName')
```

doesnt return anything but this works.

```
$filter=search.ismatch('/.Capital.*/', 'HotelName')
```

I think this has something to do with the language analyzers specified in the index but is there a way that i can make this behave just like how the database works?

**Edit**

I created a different index with sample data and changed the Analyzer for the Name Field to use a custom analyzer based on Keyword_v2 tokenizer and Lowercase tokenfilter this would store the string as is, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching#use-custom-analyzers)

This works fine for prefix,infix searches for eg.

```
search = Cap*
search = /.*Cap.*/
```

However, suffix search doesnt work -

```
search=/.*tal./
```

which should work based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_wildcard)

wondering whether the search syntax for suffix is different or is there anyother way to perform suffix searches?

Answer (score 0):

A search for *Cap* should not match the token Capital. This is expected behavior. Wildcard searches are supported. You can perform wildcard queries across all searchable properties. Or it can be scoped to only search within the HotelName property:

```
search=HotelName:Cap*
```

This will return the results you expect

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "HotelId": "24",
        "HotelName": "Gacc Capital",
        "Category": "Budget"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "HotelId": "34",
        "HotelName": "Cap'n Jack's Waterfront Inn",
        "Category": "Budget"
    }
]
```

Edit: If your requirement is to match the start of the name, you could use:

```
search=HotelName:"Cap'n*"&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=all&$select=HotelId,HotelName
```

which will return a single hit

```
"@odata.count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1.219939,
        "HotelId": "34",
        "HotelName": "Cap'n Jack's Waterfront Inn"
    }
]
```

PS: In your original question you use regular expression syntax, but your intent is to match the entire line. The documentation says regular expression are matched against single words.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. In the above example Cap* should only return the docs with Name starting with Cap which means that it should return only the second doc but not the first one. Any thing that can be done to make this working similar to the Database?
Also, i couldnt get this syntax working in the Azure Search explorer but in a sample application with QueryType set to Full.
Another thing that i noticed is that, the suffix searches are not working for e.g. this one is not working
`/.*Inn./`
which should return the second doc but returns no results.

Comment: I updated my response with an example to match the start of the field.

Comment: I updated the question with my findings. As you said regular expression are matched against single words so i changed the field to use a custom analyzer with Keyword_v2 tokenizer that doesnt generate any tokens, this should serve my purpose but it doesnt work for suffix searches any advice on this?